# C++ multicast data feed filter

Tags: c++, multicast

I am new to multicast data feed processing, my question is what's the best way to create a simple filter on the data flow.

I am writing an application to process streaming financial data, e.g., stock prices of all the stocks traded on New York Stock Exchange. The data stream looks something like this.

```
SJYM2 Quote: Bid=91.265000, 4 Ask=91.330000, 4
6SM2 Quote: Bid=1.105500, 23 Ask=1.105800, 5
RFM2 Quote: Bid=1.204500, 6 Ask=1.205000, 7
6SM2 Quote: Bid=1.105500, 24 Ask=1.105800, 5
6SM2 Quote: Bid=1.105500, 25 Ask=1.105800, 5
6SM2 Quote: Bid=1.105500, 26 Ask=1.105800, 5
6SM2 Quote: Bid=1.105500, 27 Ask=1.105800, 5
6SM2 Quote: Bid=1.105500, 28 Ask=1.105800, 5
GEH3-GEZ3 Quote: Bid=23.500000, 325 Ask=24.500000, 1501
GE:BF_M2-H3-Z3 Quote: Bid=-15.500000, 936 Ask=-14.000000, 16
GEM3-GEU3 Quote: Bid=7.500000, 21823 Ask=8.000000, 79
GE:DF_H3H4H5H6 Quote: Bid=-21.000000, 6 Ask=-19.000000, 4
NGG3-NGQ3 Quote: Bid=-0.162000, 2 Ask=-0.081000, 1
NGH3-NGU3 Quote: Bid=-0.185000, 3 Ask=-0.102000, 1
BZK2 Quote: Bid=123.970000, 1 Ask=124.120000, 1
BZ:C1_HO-BZ_K2 Quote: Bid=11.100000, 1 Ask=11.320000, 1
BZ:C1_RB-BZ_K2 Quote: Bid=17.060000, 1 Ask=17.310000, 1
BZM2 Quote: Bid=123.250000, 1 Ask=123.460000, 1
BZN2 Quote: Bid=122.530000, 1 Ask=122.920000, 1
CLK2-BZK2 Quote: Bid=-18.770000, 1 Ask=-18.610000, 1
BZK2 Quote: Bid=123.970000, 1 Ask=124.110000, 5
BZ:C1_HO-BZ_K2 Quote: Bid=11.110000, 1 Ask=11.320000, 1
BZ:C1_RB-BZ_K2 Quote: Bid=17.070000, 2 Ask=17.310000, 1
BZM2 Quote: Bid=123.250000, 1 Ask=123.450000, 5
BZN2 Quote: Bid=122.530000, 1 Ask=122.910000, 1
```

If I am only interested in **BZN2**, **BZK2** and **6SM2** data, what's the best way to create a simple filter to pull only those data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the marker always goes at the first place in the string, you can split each incoming string by the space, take the first substring and compare it with a set of patterns using `strcmp()`.
 You could also use regexp here, but it's not needed.

And the very best solution (i don't know if it's possible in your case) is to filter the incoming stream from the server side, i.e. choose the markers you need when you sign up for the stream.

Comment: I thought about using strcmp(), but the problem is that I might need to pull data for 20 different stocks, so for each new message, I may have to go through 20 strcmp(), is there any faster way to solve this problem?

Comment: If this front-end issue is critical for your performance, the best way is to substitute `strcmp || strcmp || strcmp || ...` with a lexical analyzer. There is a possible workaround - you can collect statistics about most frequent markers and compare them first.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of substitute strcmp || strcmp || strcmp || ... with a lexical analyzer? I was thinking about putting 20 symbol in to a std::map, then calling map.find() method. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is needed if you don't conduct deep performance study. When you write strcmps, get the profiling data, re-organize strcmps and still have the bottleneck in the front-end - you should use the LA for this task. But I gues that won't happen :)

Comment: 20 `strcmp()` aren't going to take too long to run, but if profiling indicates this is a performance bottleneck take a look at `regcomp()` and `regexec()`.  Also, `man flex` for info on a lexical analyzer.

Comment: Here is a more twisted idea: create a hash function char* -> int and make a switch statement ^_^